# The limit of derivative converge to zero, is the function bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$f(t)$ is continuous on the time interval $[0, \infty)$, $\dot{f}(t)=-C(t)f(t)-b(t)$, where $C(t)\ge 0$, if $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}C(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}b(t)=0$, is $f(t)$ bounded? if $b(t)$ is bounded, is $f(t)$ bounded?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to this forum!

As for your question, consider $f(t) = \sqrt t $. Clearly, the limit of the derivative approaches zero but the function itself is not bounded.

Comment: How about this question, $f(t)$ is continuouse on the time interval $[0, \infty)$, $\dot{f}(t)=-C(t)f(t)-b(t)$, where $C(t)>=0$, if $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}C(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}b(t)=0$, is $f(t)$ bounded?

Comment: Using the example I gave you, try to pick $C(t)$ and $b(t)$ appropriately such that all hypotheses hold, but the conclusion fails.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the previous comment. Take $b(t)=0$ for simplicity. Note that $f(t) = \mbox{exp}(-D(t))$ with $D'(t) = C(t)$. Now, $D(t)$ is a function which has positive derivative. What does that imply about $D$?

Comment: If $D(t)=\sqrt {t}$, f(t) will bounded converge to zero.

Comment: @ThomasBakx: Vanishing $b$ is not going to work in any counterexample, for (as you note) in this case $f(t)=f(0)\exp(-D(t))$ is clearly bounded. (I take $D$ with $D(0)=0$.)

Comment: thanks, still bounded